# how to get data from an anonymous user without giving him access to the web application

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a project. it's a support application.
After I close the ticket I send a satisfaction form to the customer via Email, it's a 5 star type of form.
I want to be able to get the data from the user and save it.
**Exemple :**
Tom had a problem with his order and our team fixes the problem. After closing the ticket.
I send a satisfaction form like this :
*How good was our service Tom rate us please*
Tom clicks on 4 stars.
**This is how I am trying to solve the problem now:**
Tom is redirected to a page that says "Thank you for your trust in our service"
and The rating is saved as a post method like this **www.oursite.com\thankyou\4**
now it should be easy to save tom's review in our server but **the problem is :**
TOM does not have access to **oursite.com** and he is redirected to the login page instead.
**My question is:** how to give tom access to **www.oursite.com\thankyou** as a visitor only.
**This is my access Control in security.yml**

```
access_control:
#        - { path: ^/dashBoard, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, allow_if: "not has_role('ROLE_USER')" }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/faq/application, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/faq/category, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: ^/api/login,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/getToken,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
#           This is the Thank you page       
        - { path: ^/thankYou, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

*if you need anything else please tell me. Maybe there is a better way to get data from an Email without redirecting the user to another page.*
**And Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I had a firewall that redirect me to the login page everytime I am connected anonymously.
this is the firewall I am talking about :

```
backend:

      pattern: ^/
      provider: fos_userbundle
      form_login:
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                default_target_path: dashboard
#                success_handler: my_user_log.component.authentication.handler.login_success_handler
      logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
#                success_handler: my_user_log.component.authentication.handler.logout_success_handler      # redirect, no_redirect, redirect_without_path
      anonymous: true
```

and this is the firewall I had to add :

```
        api_thankyou:
            pattern: ^/mail
            security: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that **Symfony goes down each access_control one-by-one**. As soon as it finds one that matches, **it uses that one and stops**. So when it gets to `^/`, it notices all pages are authenticated and redirect to the login page

To avoid that, the authentication path for the thankYou page should be above the `/^` access control:

```
access_control:
#        - { path: ^/dashBoard, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
#           This is the Thank you page       
        - { path: ^/thankYou, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, allow_if: "not has_role('ROLE_USER')" }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/faq/application, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/faq/category, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: ^/api/login,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/getToken,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: I tried that @Clement and still not working , I have an idea how access_control works and still I can't figure out what's the problem, I should mention that when I remove ^/ everything works fine but all the pages that are not stated here becomes vulnerable which is not a solution in my case , I would appreciate another solution